# How to compress HTTP response?

Tags: gzip, httpresponse

I have a HTTP response request that is too big and slow (1.2 mb, 15 seconds, plain text). I want to compress using gzip but the server is not mine. Then I use the data for a [chart](https://www.chartjs.org/)

For example. I need this response to be compress:

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20

Is it possible?

I use this code that works great:

```
$.post("http://serverNotMine", function() {}, "text")
    .done(function(data) {
        // my code for a chart.js
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("Error");
    });
```

How can I know if the server accepts gzip?

Comment: You can try to set the `Accept-Encoding` header, but the server is free to ignore this, and the server will then respond with the `Content-Encoding` header. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding

If the server ignores your `Accept-Encoding` request, then this likely isn't possible.

Comment: On my end, with that API, using Python and requests, it's working. `requests.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20', headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'})`, is, in fact, gzip compressing the data.

Answer (score 1):

The `Accept-Encoding` HTTP [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) primarily exists for this purpose, so you can specify a target encoding and the server will respond with the desired encoding among a list of choices. However, the server can choose to ignore this request, unless `identity` is explicitly prohibited, in which case the server can respond with a 406 error.

However, luckily for you, the server you're attempting to contact does, in fact, support the `Accept-Encoding` header with gzip.

```py
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/20', 
headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'})
>>> response.headers['content-encoding']
'gzip'
```

Just use your HTTP client of choice with the above header. However, it is possible using the default configurations your client was already using a compression algorithm.